# How to explain the difference between those 2 creations of broadcast streams?

Tags: stream, dart

Depending how I create the broadcast stream/streamController the result is not the same.

With `StreamController.broadcast()`:

```
final sc = StreamController.broadcast();
final stream = sc.stream;
print(stream.isBroadcast);
stream.length.then(print);
stream.length.then(print);
sc..add('')..close();
stream.length.then(print);
stream.length.then(print);
```

I get the output:

```
true
c0
d0
a1
b1
```

With `StreamController.stream.asBroadcastStream()`:

```
final sc = StreamController();
final stream = sc.stream.asBroadcastStream();
print(stream.isBroadcast);
stream.length.then(print);
stream.length.then(print);
sc..add('')..close();
stream.length.then(print);
stream.length.then(print);
```

I get the output:

```
true
a1
b1
c1
d1
```

How to explain the differences?

(I made this test on DartPad SDK 2.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/50266#issuecomment-1287127170) `asBroadcastStream` is merely a means to have multiple listeners to a single-subscription stream, which behaves differently when it comes to dropping events compared to an actual broadcast stream. A true broadcast stream (which is created through `StreamController.broadcast`) can safely drop events when there's no listener, while a single-subscription stream actually buffers these.